# Как спрятать все табы в Bootstrap tabs?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

В jQuery UI есть возможность спрятать весь tab-content, а как это сделать в Bootstrap Tabs?

```
$('.nav-tabs > li').mouseout( function(){
   $(this).find('a').tab('hide');
});
```

вот такая запись не дает необходимого результата

Comment: Вам нужно скрывать только текущий таб, с которого уходит указатель мыши или все табы когда с какого-либо уходит указатель мыши?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> В jQuery UI есть возможность спрятать весь tab-content, а как это
>   сделать в Bootstrap Tabs?

```
$('.nav-tabs > li').mouseout( function(){
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    $(".tab-content").find($(this).find("a").attr("href")).removeClass('active');
});
```

**[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8fnnsv0c/)**

---

**UPD** по вопросу из комментариев

> пользователь наводит мышь на ссылку, открывается контент, и он может
>   водить, кликать по контенту, но как только клик за пределами табов,
>   контент автоматически срывается.

```
$('.nav-tabs > li').hover(
function(){
    $(this).find("a").tab('show');
},
function(){
    if(!$($(this).find("a").attr("href")).is(":hover")){
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $(".tab-content").find($(this).find("a").attr("href")).removeClass('active');
    }
});

$('.tab-content').mouseout( function(){
    $('.tab-content > .tab-pane').removeClass("active");
    $('.nav-tabs > li').removeClass("active");
});
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8fnnsv0c/3/)**

Comment: работает, но не совсем так, когда наводим на ссылку (hover), контент должен появляться, а если ховер мимо кнопок то закрывается весь контент. На старте весь контент спрятан.

Comment: @zorro под ссылкой Вы подразумеваете `tab` (`nav-tabs > li`), а под контентом  контент для `tab` ?

Comment: да, но смотрите, если мышей навести на контент, то он также будет виден при этом (нет жесткой привязки только к ссылке)

Comment: пользователь наводит мышь на ссылку, открывается контент, и он может водить, кликать по контенту, но как только клик за пределами табов, контент автоматически срывается

Comment: ой сорри mouseout

Comment: Интересует: а вообще такое реально что бы на ссылку taba было два воздействия: click и hover, соответственно действия с контентом происходили разные? При клике открывался один контент, при hovere другой. Или click и hover это составляющие одного процесса? Не знаю правильно ли сформулировал вопрос?

Comment: @zorro события разные и да, возможно показывать разные контенты, но это не совсем правильно если Вы используете bootstrap, да и зачем такие извращения?

Comment: да я понимаю, можно переписать tabs, просто мне интересно было возможно ли такое, а какие тогда лучше использовать tab, просто jquery?

Comment: @zorro все зависит от Вашего кода, можно и на jquery без bootstrap, можно и при помощи bootstrap. на вкус и цвет...

Comment: ок, а как там по моему наболевшему вопросу:) по текущих табах, чтобы прятался контент изначально, и появлялся под воздействием мыши

Comment: огромное спасибо, выручили.

Comment: сорри не разобрался, вопрос в другом, изначально контент скрыт - а он виден в первом табе

Comment: @zorro это ошибочное представление, там контент всего 1 строка, поэтому курсор может незаметно выходить за границы контента активируя его скрытие. Так будет виднее и понятнее - https://jsfiddle.net/8fnnsv0c/3/

Comment: с контентом я разобрался накидал инфы и все ок, а вот со стартом, когда активна первая вкладка

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36113/discussion-between-alex-and-zorro).